# How do I add "data-main" attribute to a script tag using rails javascript helpers?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, script-tag

Require-js commonly uses an attribute called "data-main" on the script tag. Is there a way to tell Rails' javascript tag helpers to add it, or should I just do it the old-fashioned way?

Answer (score 12):

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', :'data-main' => 42 %>`

renders as :

`<script data-main="42" src="/javascripts/application.js?1301333790" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: This is the correct answer, just add that data-main as shown by kares

Comment: what if the data-main is referencing towards another file like `%script{"data-main" => "assets/slides", :src => "assets/require-1.0.8.min.js"}`